# what would happen if I don't put a finish on my new computer desk?

Tags: desk, wood-finish

I just got this to make a computer desk, it is made of bamboo and it is 74in x 40in x 1.5in

I added a keyboard tray under it so my keyboard+mouse are not on top of it

Since it is big I might, on some occasion, put plate or bowl (to eat) while watching a video. I see this scenario as the only case where it would be good to have a finish.

Otherwise it would only hold monitor/phone/paper/pen/etc.

If I have to put a finish I want to do something easy / fast since I have no tool and I can't easily move it outside or properly sand it or put some "semi-toxic-product"

So, what could happen if I don't finish it and if I need to put a finish on it, what is the easiest method and which product?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nothing disastrous will happen if you don't finish your desk top.  I see lots of old unfinished work bench tops and shelves at work, they are not pretty like old furniture but they're still working fine.

It will be harder to keep clean - the finish on wood keeps dirt, scuffs, marks from sinking into the wood and makes them easier to wipe up.  Finishes also protect from water and sunlight, but that's more of an issue outdoors.

There are all kinds of ways to finish wood, some are very simple and easy, no tools or oils required, and some don't involve any unpleasant fumes.  You could just wipe it down with an oil - some of these have very little odor, some even have a nice citrus smell.  If you want to seal it, paste wax is inexpensive, no odor, just takes a little elbow grease to apply.